# Returning System.Spatial.Geography from asmx webservice

Tags: c#, serialization, asmx

I have to admit I was stupid because I haven't tested the concept of returning System.Spatial.Geography from asmx webservice. The problem is that I designed a whole database, filled it with sample data, I created an Entity Model for that and after this all when I wanted to write an asmx webservice that could return data from the database, I got the error, that System.Spatial.Geography is not serializable.

Is there any way to return my records without redesigning my database (and Entities) or using wrapper classes for Geography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck, my friend. You can use one of the common spatial interchange formats to send the data over the wire. Check out some of the formatters (such as [gml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.spatial.gmlformatter%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), for example).
You can send it in a number of standard formats, Gml, 'Well Known Text' aka WKT, and 'Well Known Binary' aka WKB. WKB is the smallest over the wire, since its just a simple data stream. The WKT format can get pretty verbose, but it does compress well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but I had an other big problem so in the end I had to change the database... :( Anyway, thank you! :)